# Block editing of text before given column in Vim

Tags: vim, scripting, text-editor, vim-plugin

I'm writing a plugin that presents a form to the user. All works well, but for full success it would be great if I could block editing of the first two presented columns. Basically, this equals to: `<Nop>` when `col(".") < X`, but I don't know how to hook up to every key pressed in insert mode. Is my direction correct, how to hook up to the key strokes?

More, I would also like to block editing of selected lines from first `7` lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `modifiable` inside a `CursorMoved` autocommand, for example:

```
au CursorMoved * call CheckCursorPos()

function! CheckCursorPos()
    " This code has to be improved, it's just an example:
    if col('.') <= 2
        set nomodifiable
    else
        set modifiable
    endif
endf
```

You can add more complex tests inside the function (to handle the 7 first lines for example).

To make it complete you also have to handle the `CursorMovedI` autocommand to your taste, otherwise the edition will be possible threw edit mode (for example, if you press `i` on the 4th column which is modifiable, then go back to the start of line, the edition will be possible)

Comment: Can the message "E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off" be somehow silenced?